Laravel MyISAM to InnoDB migration
I have a database that my laravel applications connects to, that has MyISAM tables.
So it doesn't show foreign keys, although they are implemented.
I created this migration to fix the issue and then I altered the line 'engine' => 'InnoDB', in database.php config for this connection;
but I can't see that foreign keys are fixed in the designer (phpmyadmin)
$tables = [
    'categories',
    'currencies',
    ...
];
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE ' . $table . ' ENGINE = InnoDB');
}

How can I fix that?

I created a migration that re-creates all foreign keys, but was hopping for the code above to fix the issue.
I did the code above once and worked fine, Idk wht this time it didn't

ISAM doesn't support foreign keys, changing the engine won't magically make keys appear where they were not before.

MyISAM accepted FOREIGN KEY declarations but ignored them.  See this for my notes on conversion from MyISAM:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb
